# Managing MEAN stack website (newbee)

Tags: mongodb, web, content-management-system, admin, meanjs

I'm relatively new to web development and i've started looking into developing with the MEAN mean stack. I have a really simple question.

SO, say im creating a simple webpage showing a list of fruits from a mongo db. the end user will only see this list of fruits. however, i want to be able to edit this list. so do i have to create another page (like an admin page) to do that? Also, how do i create it so that only i have access to the admin page.

Im guessing i have to make another page that pulls fromt he same db and edits/ adds or whatever. my concern is how am i going to keep this admin page private. note the website doesnt have any 'user logins'

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am also quite new to the mean stack. I think the easiest way of doing this will be by implementing some kind of user login system where all guests can view the list and only logged in users can edit the list. If you clone the official [git](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) repo of meanjs there is an example module called articles where users can create but everyone can view. Start from there and have a look at how they implement the privileges of each page and route. Good luck.

EDIT:

To add a default admin user when the server starts up for the first time have a look at /config/env/default.js and production.js. There you will be able to seed an admin user with default credentials. After this you can remove the signup page and routes so no one can create a new user and only leave the sign in for the default admin user.

For creating a admin page, create a new view and add it to the routes of the client but only allow an admin to request the view. Something like this in /client/config/client.config.js:

```
Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'fruits', {
  title: 'Edit fruits',
  state: 'fruits.edit',
  roles: ['admin']
});
```

and in /client/config/client.routes.js:

```
.state('fruits.edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    templateUrl: 'path/client/views/editfruit.client.view.html',
    controller: 'fruitcontroller',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    data: {
      roles: ['admin'],
      pageTitle: 'Edit fruit'
    }
  })
```

Hope this helps.